# Display realtime Training of model using tensorboard Python Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, visualization, tensorboard

I am unable to the documentation of the Tensorboard as there are many confusing stuffs for me.

I want to know how I can display the complete training and validation movements of my model in tensorboard. I want to display values and how they are playing as input and what output is getting generated and the MSE error loss for the training and validation.

Here is what tried till now. It only gives me the training loss result per iteration in an epoch.

```
seq_len = 9
## Basic Cell RNN in tensorflow
index_in_epoch = 0;
perm_array  = np.arange(x_train.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(perm_array)
# function to get the next batch
def get_next_batch(batch_size):
    global index_in_epoch, x_train, perm_array   
    start = index_in_epoch
    index_in_epoch += batch_size

    if index_in_epoch > x_train.shape[0]:
        np.random.shuffle(perm_array) # shuffle permutation array
        start = 0 # start next epoch
        index_in_epoch = batch_size

    end = index_in_epoch
    return x_train[perm_array[start:end]], y_train[perm_array[start:end]]
# parameters
n_steps = seq_len-1 
n_inputs = x_train.shape[2]#4 

n_neurons = 400 
n_outputs = y_train.shape[1]#4
n_layers = 2
learning_rate = 0.000001

batch_size = 50
n_epochs = 100#200 
train_set_size = x_train.shape[0]
test_set_size = x_test.shape[0]

tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_outputs])

# use Basic RNN Cell
layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.elu)
          for layer in range(n_layers)]                                                                 
multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
outputs = outputs[:,n_steps-1,:] # keep only last output of sequence                                     
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y)) # loss function = mean squared error 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
tf.summary.scalar('MyLoss', loss)
summ = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

Training starts like this:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
try:
    with tf.Session() as sess: 
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())        
        for iteration in range(int(n_epochs*train_set_size/batch_size)):
            x_batch, y_batch = get_next_batch(batch_size) # fetch the next training batch
            writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs", sess.graph)
            [_,s] = sess.run([training_op,summ], feed_dict={X: x_batch, y: y_batch}) 
            writer.add_summary(s, iteration)    
            if iteration % int(5*train_set_size/batch_size) == 0:
                mse_train = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_train, y: y_train}) 
                mse_valid = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_valid, y: y_valid}) 
                print('%.2f epochs: MSE train/valid = %.10f/%.10f'%(
                    iteration*batch_size/train_set_size, mse_train, mse_valid))
                save_path = saver.save(sess, "modelsOHLC\\model"+str(iteration)+".ckpt")                
            writer.close()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard stopped")
```

Please anyone please guide me what I can do to see my training and validation lively. I just cannot understand whether my data is making any sense to the model or not. Hence, visualization can become a better option for me. Please help me.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this please.

Comment: Does anyone has any suggestion please comment here. I will be delighted to here expertise over it.

Comment: I would like to know this too. THanks for the question.